# Promise is skipping XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, promise, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to do XMLHttpRequest with Promise.all
like this way

```
        Promise.all(image.map(imageUpload => {              
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr.open('POST', MY_REQUEST_URL)
            xhr.onload = () => {
              alert('imageUpload.name')
            }
            xhr.onerror = (err) => {
               alert('error')
            }
            let formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append('file', {uri: imageUpload.path, type: 'image/png', name: 'image.png'});
            xhr.send(formdata)
        })).then(async s => {
               alert('done')
        })
```

but the problem is Promise.all is not waiting until the xhr request finish, it just sends a request and alert, thats it!

any ideas?

Comment: because you're not returning a Promise in the map callback - easiest solution is to use fetch ... which returns a Promise - also the `async` in `.then(async s => ` is redundant as you're not using `await`

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry i didn't understand what u mean

Comment: Promise.all waits for an array of Promises to resolve ... where are the Promises? your .map callback doesn't even return anything, let alone a Promise

Comment: @JaromandaX so how can i solve that?

Comment: @JaromandaX actually its not redundant im using await but i did remove lines form the code cause its private API

Comment: Related: [Promise.all is returning an array of undefined and resolves before being done](/q/34813147/4642212), which is about forgetting to return a Promise in the `map` callback. Though in this case, there is nothing that _could_ be returned for `Promise.all` to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback to .map doesn't return anything - but it needs to return a Promise to work with Promise.all

```
Promise.all(image.map(imageUpload => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', MY_REQUEST_URL);
    xhr.addEventListener('load', resolve);
    xhr.addEventListener('error', reject);

    // if you must alert in a loop of XHR's add these
    // I've made this code separate because I think it's a terrible idea™
    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => alert('imageUpload.name'));
    xhr.addEventListener('error', () => alert('error'));

    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', {uri: imageUpload.path, type: 'image/png', name: 'image.png'});
    xhr.send(formdata);
}))).then(async s => {
    alert('done')
});
```

however, modern technique is to use `fetch` which is already a Promise based native API

```
Promise.all(image.map(imageUpload => {
    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', {uri: imageUpload.path, type: 'image/png', name: 'image.png'});
    return fetch(MY_REQUEST_URL, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formdata
    })
    // probably don't need this line, since you don't actually care about the response
    .then(response => response.text())
    // and if you must alert during a loop of asynchronous code ...
    // though I think it's a terrible idea™
    .then(() => alert('imageUpload.name'))
    .catch(err => {
        alert('error');
        throw err; // without this, the rest of the code thinks you've succeeded when you've failed
    });
})).then(async s => {
    alert('done');
})
```

Comment: resolve() => {
              alert('imageUpload.name')
    }

Comment: huh? why the heck do you want to alert inside an asynchronous function? I've edited the code to do as you think is wise

Comment: I've changed the code a bit to add your *alert*s even though they are very poor coding style™ especially with asynchronous code like this

Comment: thank you so much, actually i don't need the alerts i dont use them but they are just placeholders instead of axios.get and redux dispatches, actually i care about the response should i changed     .then(() => alert('imageUpload.name'))
to     .then((response) => console.log(response)) is that okay?

Comment: do whatever you need ... with fetch you'll need to process the response using response.text() (a promise) or something else depending on what the server is sending you - plenty of documentation for fetch on MDN